# Writing quotes of a business name with star as hyphen

Tags: copywriting, branding, testimonials

I have a business with a name e.g. "my business".

Wherever you see the company name it's always written as **my★business** - the company logo is similar and anywhere we write the name on the website that's how it looks.

My question is: Is there a wrong way to write this when quoting someone who has mentioned the business? For example, on our site we have a quotes section, a collection of quotes from users which we publish. One of them might be:

"I started using **my★business** after a friend told me about their website"

Is that the correct way to write the company name or should it be "my business" without the star? Or doesn't it matter?

Not sure how to tag this so apologies if incorrect.

Comment: Isn't the analogue to a star an asterisk? 

My*Business

That being said I think having non-standard letters in your business title adds needless complexity.

Answer (score 3):

This mainly regards **corporate identity** and should not affect usability very much - usually.

However, I think **you should not force people to write it with a star**, as the ★ sign is extremely hard to enter for average user (in unicode it's 2605, so it needs pressing Alt+2605 according to [this article](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm)). Instead, you should let them use "My Business" (or "My-Business", "MyBusiness").

Regarding visual representation of the brand name on your site, you can write a small JS **parser or listener** that would automatically change every appearance of "My Business", "My-Business" and "MyBusiness" (and any other popular way people write it in testimonials) to "My★Business" - just to keep the CI coherent.

However, inability to enter the star may make them feel uncomfortable (*"Hey, everyone entered it with the star, so why can't I?"*) which may result in not leaving a testimonial at all. This leads to conclusion that a listener would be better for that, as it would change each appearance of an allowed-yet-incorrect form of the brand name, giving them **visual feedback** saying *"It's fine how you wrote it, we have automatically corrected it to the proper form."*

By the way, I think you should prepare for other forms used in various media (e.g. mentions in articles) where people will use other form than the one including the star.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not really what I'm asking...it's not a case of how others would write the business name (that is a very good point though and I thank you for that, hadn't thought about it) but more a case of how we, as "my business" should write it when quoting what someone has said about "my business" e.g. John says "my business" is great!

Comment: Well, actually I don't think it matters in this case. It's your brand and it's your choice how you write it. As long as it is understandable and legible, at least, and the star does not affect it, imho.

Answer (score 2):

It's about authenticity. If you want your testimonial to look like it was actually written by (or spoken by) the user, do not include the star.

People don't write or speak company logos, they say the company's name.

I would never say "Fed[**arrow**]Ex delivered my package on time." Or "I got a great price on shampoo at Wal[**star**]Mart." The time to enforce corporate branding is in your own communication, not in communication that comes from your customers in the form of testimonials.

This is the difference between having a logotype and a company name. The logotype identifies the company in outward-facing materials. When you get mail from customers, they refer to you by your company name.